# Devolver dos datos con AJAX y JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo un formulario que valido a través de AJAX. Necesito que ajax (desde el archivo va_registro.php) me devuelva dos datos a la vez, por lo que estoy usando JSON. No consigo que me devuelva esos datos.

**registro.php** -> Este es el Formulario

```
 <!--Formulario de registro-->
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="formulario">
        <!-- En este span recibo las respuestas de Ajax -->
        <!--En este span recibo los posibles mensajes de error desde ajax-->
        <span id="mensaje"></span>
        <!--En este input recibo desde ajax la comprobacion de si hay errores o no-->
        <input type="hidden" name="ajax" id="ajax">

        <h2>Regístrate</h2>
        <?php if(!empty($errores[5])){echo $errores[5];} ?>
        <p>Usuario &nbsp;<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" value="<?php echo $usuario ?>" onBlur="validarFormulario()" required>
        <?php if(!empty($errores[0])){
                 echo $errores[0];
              }else{
                 echo '<span id="error1"></span>';
              }
        ?></p>
        <p>Contraseña &nbsp;<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" value="<?php echo $pwd ?>" onBlur="validarFormulario()" required>
        <?php if(!empty($errores[1])){echo $errores[1];}
              if(!empty($errores[4])){echo $errores[4];
              }else{
                  echo '<span id="error2"></span>';
              }
        ?></p>
        <p>Contraseña &nbsp;<input type="password" name="pwd2" value="<?php echo $pwd2 ?>"  onBlur="validarFormulario()" required>
        <?php if(!empty($errores[2])){echo $errores[2];} ?></p>
        <p>Email &nbsp;<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" onBlur="validarFormulario()" required>
        <?php if(!empty($errores[3])){echo $errores[3];
              }else{
                 echo '<span id="error3"></span>';
              }
        ?></p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="registrar" value="Registrarse"></p>
     </form>
```

**val_registro.js** -> Se supone que a través de data.respuesta y data.codigo debería de acceder a las posiciones del array creado por JSON

```
function validarFormulario(){
var dataString = $('#formulario').serialize();  
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //url desde dónde espero una respuesta
    url: "validaciones/val_registro.php", 
    data: dataString,

    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#mensaje").html(data.respuesta);
        $("#ajax").val(data.codigo);
    },
});

}
```

**val_registro.php** -> Desde aquí recibo las respuestas

```
<?php
//Creo las variables
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];

    if(strlen($usuario)<3){
        $mensaje= array('codigo' => 1, 'respuesta' => "<script>$('#error1').html('El minimo permitido son 3 caracteres')</script>");
        //header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($mensaje);
        exit();
    }else{
        $mensaje= array('codigo' => 0, 'respuesta' => "<script>$('#error1').html('BIEEEN')</script>");
        //header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($mensaje);
        exit();
    }

 }
?>
```

Está mostrando todo el array entero, y además, lo que hay en la posición "respuesta" lo muestra como vacío. Esto es lo que recibo:

```
{"codigo":1,"respuesta":"
```

Comment: Gracias Winston, pero sigue igual

Comment: Lo que recibo como respuesta es lo siguiente: `{"codigo":1,"respuesta":" `

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tienes código HTML en el valor que vas a pasar a `json_encode` y entonces el resultado no siempre va a ser el esperado. Como sugiere [asachanfbd en su respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056253/3695983), lo que debes hacer es indicarle a `json_encode` que vas a pasar texto con código HTML y comillas para que los escape correctamente.

Algo que aplicado a tu caso se vería así:

```
echo json_encode($mensaje, JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG);
```

---

Ahora, quizás deberías plantearte cambiar el código un poco para no devolver HTML sino sólo el mensaje y aplicarlo en JavaScript, en lugar de pasar el JavaScript que debe ejecutarse (lo cual puede no ser una buena idea).

Entones val_registro.php sería algo como esto:

```
<?php
//Creo las variables
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];

    if(strlen($usuario)<3){
        $mensaje= array('codigo' => 1, 'respuesta' => "El minimo permitido son 3 caracteres'");
        //header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($mensaje);
        exit();
    }else{
        $mensaje= array('codigo' => 0, 'respuesta' => "BIEEEN");
        //header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($mensaje);
        exit();
    }

}
```

Y en el val_registro.js tendrías algo como esto:

```
function validarFormulario(){
var dataString = $('#formulario').serialize();  
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //url desde dónde espero una respuesta
    url: "validaciones/val_registro.php", 
    data: dataString,

    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#error1').text(data.respuesta);
        $("#ajax").val(data.codigo);
    },
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que falta es [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

```
function validarFormulario(){
var dataString = $('#formulario').serialize();  
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  //url desde dónde espero una respuesta
  url: "validaciones/val_registro.php", 
  data: dataString,

  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function (data) {
      json = JSON.parse(data);
      $("#mensaje").html(json.respuesta);
      $("#ajax").val(json.codigo);
    },
  });

}
```